# Looking for a good practice for dealing with repository in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Currently I've got repository class for each data model for data access.

In the homepage, I need to display the top 5 records from each repository. So in the HomeController, I would need to have a lot of repository members, which doesn't feel right. Is there any good solution for this?

Thank you very much for your help. Any advice is welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a service layer which will aggregate those five repositories into a single business operation. Example:

```
public interface IItemsService
{
    IEnumerable<Item> GetTopItems();
}
```

and the implementation of this service will use as much repositories as required. Now your controller simply becomes:

```
public class ItemsController : Controller
{
    private readonly IItemsService _itemsService;
    public ItemsController(IItemsService itemsService)
    {
        _itemsService = itemsService;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var topItems = _itemsService.GetTopItems();
        return View(topItems);
    }
}
```

And in the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<AppName.Models.Item>
<h2>Top items</h2>
@Html.DisplayForModel()
```

which uses the item display template (`~/Views/Items/DisplayTemplates/Item.cshtml`):

```
@model AppName.Models.Item
<div>@Model.Title</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do a generic Repository for basic operations, and inherit it when creating repositories for each entity in part.

but this way you would still need 5 instances or the generic repository.

so there are 2 ways:

1)

create a repository `UniRepo`

which has Generic Methods like `Get<T>(int id)`, etc.

and use it in your `HomeController`

2)

don't put any instance of repository in `HomeController`, instead

create 5 controllers for each entity, and in each you put an instance of a repository, and create an action for that list

and in the home/index view you do

```
@Html.Action("list","entity1");
@Html.Action("list","entity2");
@Html.Action("list","entity3");
```

Html.Action is equivalent to RenderAction

Answer (score 0):

I second Darin Dimitrov's response.

In my experience it is usual (in desktop development) to have a service layer that does all the talking to your repositories.

e.g.

1. View Model
2. Service
3. Repository1 : Repository 2
4. Data Access 1 : Data Access 2

then from the top end your only ever calling your service(s) which keeps things neet.